# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Key") is not reading value from azure functions configuration

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-functions

I have azure functions that is triggered by service bus queue. Everything is working fine in local. I have added the ServiceBusConnectionString in azure portal's configuration But still Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString") is returning null.
There are few similar problems available in stackoverflow. But None of these solution works.

```
public class ServiceBusPolar
    {
        private readonly IEmailService _emailRepo;
        private readonly string BASEURL;
        private static HttpClient httpClient;
        public static string QUEUE_NAME;
        public static string ServiceBusConnectionString;
        public ServiceBusPolar(IEmailService emailRepo)
        {
            _emailRepo = emailRepo;
            BASEURL = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("BaseURL");
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            QUEUE_NAME = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MessageQueueName");
            ServiceBusConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString");
            
            //Utl = new Utility();
        }

        [FunctionName("ServiceBusPolar")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("emailqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] Message message, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"MessageQueueName is {QUEUE_NAME} and Service bus connection string is {ServiceBusConnectionString} and directly {Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusConnectionString")}");
            
            string payload = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body);

            //More logic below is removed to make the code short
                
            }
        }

        


        
    }
```

In above code, I have logged the QueueName and ServiceBusConnectionString. But when this function runs in production, These fields are coming empty.
[image]
We can clearly see in this above picture that fields are coming null.

Screenshot of my configuration inside azure portal.

[image]